# MySQL function is returning wrong value

Tags: mysql, function

I have a function with 4 parameters and for example if I set null/empty value for the first parameter which is type DATE I get the result 2 instead of 1.

```
SET @p0=''; SET @p1=''; SET @p2=''; SET @p3=''; SELECT `MY_FN`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3) AS `MY_FN`;
```

My code:

```
BEGIN
 IF PARAM1_DATE IS NULL or PARAM1_DATE='' THEN 
        SET @STATUS = 1;
    ELSE 
        SET @STATUS = 2;
    END IF;
    
    
    RETURN @STATUS;
END
```

I've tried also ISNULL(NULLIF(PARAM1_DATE,'') same result

Comment: Go on add rest of function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the validation of parameters OCCURS BEFORE function code is executed you need to make sure a valid date (if that's what param1_date datatype is) is passed in the call to the function. if you want to pass any old rubbish then define as char and test in function..